# Parsing JSON from ok HTTP response

Tags: php, android, json

Log shows response like this:

[image: Image 1]

I sent a PHP array using JSON encode from server which outputs this:

[image: Image 2]

How can I get my array from the unexpected response code? The array is sent as JSON encode.

PHP:

```
<?php

require "conn.php"; 
class person {
        public $id;
        public $age;
        public $name;
        public $lat;
        public $longi;
        public $email;
        public $image;
        public $number;
    }


$bloodgroup = $_POST["bloodgroup"];
$sql = "Select * from UserDetails where bloodgroup = '$bloodgroup'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$donorsArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $donor = new person;
        $donor->id = $row["ID"];
        $donor->age = $row["age"];
        $donor->name = $row["Name"];
        $donor->lat = $row["lat"];
        $donor->longi = $row["longi"];
        $donor->email = $row["email"];
        $donor->image = $row["image"];
        $donor->number = $row["number"]; 
        $donorsArray[] = $donor;
    }
} else {
}

echo json_encode(array_values($donorsArray));

?>
```

Java:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("bloodgroup",bloodgroup)
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://blooddonation.byethost6.com/GetDonorsDetails.php")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String res = response.body().string();

            Log.e("responseaaa",res);

            // Do something with the response.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("responseaaa","with error "+e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: You again :) I see you listened to my advice in using OkHttp. Good. Now this raw php is ugly, but what can you do. You need to set the header in your response to be `json` like this `header('Content-Type: application/json');` Because now the server is returning html with a json string. After that you can edit the question, so we can help you parse the proper json you get from the server.

Comment: @Vucko somthing like this ?  
Response response =client.newCall(request).execute();
response.header("Content-Type: application/json");

Comment: I'd guess from your SQL injection vulnerability that I could use a `UNION` to read entries from your user table - don't put this live until you have fixed this!

Comment: No, I mean to set the header in php.

Comment: If you are working on a medical application then it is possible you should consider **getting a security professional to assess your code** before you use it in a production environment.

Comment: @Vucko i tried but not working i guess the problem is with the server. 
just look at this link. i guess my issue  is same as this one because i am also using free hosting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409655/getting-html-response-instead-of-json-in-android
what u say ?

Comment: @halfer okay sir :-)

Comment: @halfer how can i prolong the connection timeout in httpok ? setConnectTimeout method is not resolved by okhttpclient object :-(

Comment: I'm not  a Java programmer, so am unlikely to be able to help - maybe @Vucko can shed some light?