# Android online server receiving JavaScript response instead of Json?

Tags: javascript, php, android, server

So I have tested my Android application on my localhost , no problems at all.Now I'm trying to upload the php files on my online website along with the database that I used on my localhost.
I already read the following [Cookies sent by server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409655/getting-html-response-instead-of-json-in-android)
But I dont see any cookies sent.

I can see the following

```
09-08 12:33:33.637 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/Response Code:  ... 200
09-08 12:33:33.637 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/Response Code: Headers-------start-----
09-08 12:33:33.637 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Date:Thu, 08 Sep 2016 04:34:47 GMT
09-08 12:33:33.637 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Content-Type:text/html
09-08 12:33:33.637 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Transfer-Encoding:chunked
09-08 12:33:33.637 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Connection:keep-alive
09-08 12:33:33.637 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Vary:Accept-Encoding
09-08 12:33:33.638 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
09-08 12:33:33.638 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Cache-Control:no-cache
09-08 12:33:33.638 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: X-Android-Selected-Protocol:http/1.1
09-08 12:33:33.638 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: X-Android-Sent-Millis:1473309212446
09-08 12:33:33.638 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: X-Android-Received-Millis:1473309213636
09-08 12:33:33.638 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: X-Android-Response-Source:NETWORK 200
09-08 12:33:33.638 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/Response Code: Headers-------end-----
09-08 12:33:33.640 4555-5690/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/Before_parsing:: <html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("7c37be3e9d2b34968579877c85060bcb");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://busted.byethost16.com/Andriod/login_with_route.php?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

Then I get this error

```
 Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here's my android code

```
        if (methodType.equals("login")) {
        try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            routeType = params[3];
            String lat = params[4];
            String lng = params[5];


            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
           // httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("type", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(routeType, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("lat", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lat, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("lng", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lng, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            // normally, 3xx is redirect
            int status = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            Log.i("Response Code"," ... " + status);

            String key;
            Log.i("Response Code","Headers-------start-----");
            for (int i = 1; (key = httpURLConnection.getHeaderFieldKey(i)) != null; i++) {
                System.out.println(key + ":" + httpURLConnection.getHeaderField(i));
            }
            Log.i("Response Code","Headers-------end-----");


            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));


            String result = "";
            String line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.i("Before_parsing:", result);

            // Parsing JSON data
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                Log.i("log_tag", "JSONObject: " + object);
                returnString = object.getString("message");
                successResponse = object.optInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                Log.i("log_tag:", "successResponse: " + successResponse);
                if (successResponse != null && successResponse == 1) {//logged in successfully "
                    backgroundProcessResult = true;
                    userId = object.getString("user_id"); //get the user id from the database (so we use it to log out)
                    Log.i("log_tag:", "received user id " + userId);
                }
                else{
                    backgroundProcessResult = false;
                    Log.i("log_tag:", "something went wrong, ");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            Log.i("log_tag", "returnString: " + returnString);


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

my PHP on my online server:

```
<?php  
 require_once('database.php');
// array for JSON response
$response = array();


//check the server method first
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$useremail = null;
$password = null;
//received as string
$unconverted_lat = $_POST['lat'];
$unconverted_lng = $_POST['lng'];
$type =null;


    if(empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["password"]) ) {
        // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

        }
        if( empty($_POST["type"]) ){
            $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Please select a route type";
        echo json_encode($response);
        }


    if(!empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $useremail = $_POST["email"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `user_email` = ? and `user_password` = PASSWORD(?)");
        $query->bind_param("ss", $useremail, $password);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($userid);
        $query->fetch();
        $query->close();

        //valid(username and password in db)
        if(!empty($userid)) { 

        $lat = (float)$unconverted_lat;
        $lng = (float)$unconverted_lng;
        $type =$_POST['type'];

            //start session
            session_start();
            session_regenerate_id(true); 
            $session_key = session_id();
            $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `sessions` ( `user_id`, `session_key`, `session_address`, `session_useragent`,                       `session_expires`) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 16 HOUR) );");
            $query->bind_param("isss", $userid, $session_key, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
            $query->execute();
            $query->close();

            //update the markers table
            $query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `markers`(`user_id`,  `lat`, `lng`, `type`)
            VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lat='$lat', lng='$lng', type='$type'");
            $query->bind_param("idds", $userid,$lat, $lng, $type );
            $query->execute();
            $query->close();

            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "logged in successfully";
            $response["user_id"] = $userid ;
            echo json_encode($response); 


        }
            //not valid(email or/and password not in db)
        else {
            // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "account not found please check login info";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);

        }
    }
}       

 ?>
```

the link Im trying to test
http://busted.byethost16.com/Andriod/login_with_route.php
.side question, why does it change to
http://busted.byethost16.com/Andriod/login_with_route.php?i=1
when I get the response back?

Comment: put exit() after every return json response in your server code or json_encode($response,true);

Comment: Thanks for the help , I tried exit(); nothing changes in the response nor the error. 
Same thing with  json_encode($response,true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I switched to another free hosting site and now my php works and I get the correct response:

```
    09-08 21:24:01.452 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/Response Code:  ... 200
09-08 21:24:01.452 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/Response Code: Headers-------start-----
09-08 21:24:01.452 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Server:Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_mono/2.6.3 mod_jk/1.2.37 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_wsgi/4.4.13 Python/2.4.3
09-08 21:24:01.452 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.41
09-08 21:24:01.452 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
09-08 21:24:01.452 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
09-08 21:24:01.453 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Pragma:no-cache
09-08 21:24:01.453 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=c0d87c4d1218264413d57183a4966009; path=/
09-08 21:24:01.453 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
09-08 21:24:01.453 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Connection:Keep-Alive
09-08 21:24:01.453 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Transfer-Encoding:chunked
09-08 21:24:01.453 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: Content-Type:text/html
09-08 21:24:01.453 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: X-Android-Selected-Protocol:http/1.1
09-08 21:24:01.454 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: X-Android-Sent-Millis:1473341040653
09-08 21:24:01.454 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: X-Android-Received-Millis:1473341041452
09-08 21:24:01.455 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/System.out: X-Android-Response-Source:NETWORK 200
09-08 21:24:01.455 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/Response Code: Headers-------end-----
09-08 21:24:01.456 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/Before_parsing:: {"success":1,"message":"logged in successfully","user_id":6}  
09-08 21:24:01.456 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/log_tag: JSONObject: {"success":1,"message":"logged in successfully","user_id":6}
09-08 21:24:01.457 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/log_tag:: successResponse: 1
09-08 21:24:01.458 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/log_tag:: received user id 6
09-08 21:24:01.458 23578-24362/com.example.meer.bustedtracking I/log_tag: returnString: logged in successfully
```

my PHP code is still the same .
so there's something going on with the hosting service that caused the unwanted response .if anyone knows why please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

put in you server code Top

```
ob_start("ob_tidyhandler");
```

or put it on your code

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Tried both it didnt change the response , it is still 200 and Content-Type:text/html

Comment: on a web browser it does receive the content as 'Content-Type:application/json'